# React Native 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found in AppDelegate.m:

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-maps

Environment info
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.3"
"react-native-maps": "^0.29.4"

XCode Version 13.1 (13A1030d)
macOS 12.0.1
Target Platform iOS 15.1 Phone using GoogleMaps

Steps to reproduce
Create new project
Add config = use_native_modules! in the Podfile
Add in the Podfile:

react-native-maps dependencies
rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'

pod install

Add in AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary
*)launchOptions
{
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"xxxx"];
[GMSPlacesClient provideAPIKey:@"xxxx"];
}
```

Build in XCode

Describe what you expected to happen:

Build successful

Describe what you actually happens:

/ios/UbiWalkerReactNat/AppDelegate.m:2:9: 'GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h' file not found[image]

Comment: in AppDelegate.m already imported -> #import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <GooglePlaces/GooglePlaces.h>

Answer (score 0):

you need to first import `import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>` in `AppDelegate.m` see [here](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#enabling-google-maps).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be solved, there was a WARNING on pod install:
[!] The xxx [Debug] target overrides the FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS build setting defined in Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-xxx-xxx/Pods-xxx-xxx.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation - Use the $(inherited)` flag, or

- Remove the build settings from the target.

I've SOLVED with $(inherited) flag on Build Settings.